# Facebook Wall Graph API - not getting timestamp

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook wall on a website so users can see their current facebook wall but I am not getting the timestamp for each post.
How do I show the timestamp?
How do I refresh the wall posts?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you accessing `{userid}/feed`? If so, posts definitely include the timestamp. Post some code and we'll take a look.

```
"type": "status",
"created_time": "2012-02-19T17:03:28+0000",
"updated_time": "2012-02-19T20:24:43+0000",`
```